# Could not parse the remainder: '{{' from '{{' when comparing dates in Django

Tags: django

I have a field in my model as below, which defines a date:

```
usedate = models.DateField(default=date.today)
```

I now want to be able to compare that date to todays date, to see if it's late. I've added the below to my html & it prints the correct date for today:

```
{% now "Y-m-d" as todays_date %}
{{ todays_date }}
```

I'm now trying to compare todays date with the date in my model, using the below. But I get the error "Could not parse the remainder: '{{' from '{{'"

Can anyone help?

```
   {% if todays_date > {{ todo.usedate }} %}
   <b>You're Late!</b>
{% endif %}
```

**Update**
removing the curly braces around todo.usedate gets rid of the error, but the if statement doesn't resolve as true, even when it is true. It looks like the default DateField format and the yyyy-mm-dd format of todays_date are the same and it should work, but it seems to not be - any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should *not* add surrounding curly brackets for a variable in a template tag. You can make a comparison with:

```
{% if todays_date > todo.usedate %}
...
{% endif %}
```

One uses curly brackets to *print* a variable in a template.

Here however you compare a *string* (`todays_date` with a `date` object). You thus better pass the current `date` to your view, like:

```
from datetime import date

def some_view(request):
    # ...
    todo = ...
    today = date.today()
    return render(request, 'app/some_template.html', {'todo': todo, 'today': today})
```

and then render it as:

```
{% if today > todo.usedate %}
...
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks - that gets rid of the error, but the if statement doesn't resolve as true, even when it is true. It looks like the default DateField format and the yyyy-mm-dd format of todays_date are the same and it should work, but it seems to not be - any idea?

Comment: @kikee1222: yes, you compare strings with a `date` object. Don't do that. Pass the current day to the template.